# Нужна ли запятая перед КАК в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Уже сегодня, с повальным приобщением к социальной сети "Инстаграм", можно наблюдать (,) как "спускаются" данные установки, приживаясь в низкоресурсных семьях

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна: союз ***как*** соединяет части  сложноподчиненного предложения. Ср.:  ***Мы долго смотрели, как тлеют угли костра.***